# Can JSONB GIN indexes be specified in CodeFirst EntityFramework with NPGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I've got some JSONB columns on my EF code first objects in an EFCore project.  I would like to set up some GIN indexes to properties inside those strongly typed objects being stored as JSONB property/column.
Is this possible? (currently using the postgres:latest image)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Since `.ForNpgsqlHasMethod("gin")` is obsolete, with EF Core 3.1 you can use this:

```
metaBuilder
    .HasIndex(x => x.DocumentNumber)
    .HasMethod("gin")
    .HasOperators("gin_trgm_ops");
```

and your migration will look like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_DocumentContentMeta_DocumentNumber",
    table: "DocumentContentMeta",
    column: "DocumentNumber")
    .Annotation("Npgsql:IndexMethod", "gin")
    .Annotation("Npgsql:IndexOperators", new[] { "gin_trgm_ops" });
```

Comment: Id there anything else you need to do with postgres database to enable support? I'm getting exception: `'42704: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"`.

Does this require specific Postgresql version to work?

Comment: @nikib3ro yes, try execute `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;` on your database

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually u can do it like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
       .HasIndex(a => new { a.Album })
       .ForNpgsqlHasMethod("gin");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

and when u run ef add migration, the sql query generated will be like:

CREATE INDEX ix_artist_album ON artist USING gin ("album");

Documentation in Npgsql: http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/indexes.html

Comment: For some reason I thought I saw Entity Framework 6 in the original post, not Entity Framework Core...

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1: Create Index**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyAwesomeModel>()
    .HasIndex(f => f.stringToTriGram)
    .HasMethod("gin")
    .HasOperators("gin_trgm_ops");
```

**Step 2: Enable TrigramExtension**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("pg_trgm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way to set up GIN indices via the Npgsql EF6 provider. However, you can use raw SQL in your migrations to set it up manually.

However, as @hellokitty5685 wrote in another answer, this is possible in EF Core.

Comment: Thanks, was afraid of that.  That being the case, I'm immediately thinking about creating a custom attribute that contains the GIN index info for the property it would applied to.  Do you know if there is a pattern for managing manual schema alterations from within the service project?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean - you're going to have to create a migration yourself and manually write the SQL for adding the index. By the way, note that the EF Core provider does have support for specifying GIN indices: http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/indexes.html

Comment: Was staring at the page you referenced (again).  I'm wondering if a custom Operator couldnt be written once in the DB and then use ForNpgsqlHasOperators to cover any number of JSONB fields with normal looking indices in EF.  In this example a GiST index approach is being written w/ a Create Operator...I'll look into perhaps doing this with a GIN variant: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createopclass.html.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to create a GIN index without `CREATE INDEX ... USING gin`... But I'm not a big expert there.